# VBA Excel limitation on ActiveX Option Buttons

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I try to make some questionnaire in excel (yes, I know that there are better ways to do that ;-)

I have several sheets in it and each one contains some ActiveX Option Buttons to select (Yes / No).

The thing is that when I select some questions in first, second sheet and go further to the next one, some Option Buttons from previous sheets are becoming unchecked again. I can't see exact pattern here because some sheets preserve all states of the option buttons, some lose them all and some have them checked differently.

So my question: is there some special limitation on this matter? I have many ActiveX objects in my workbook if this matters.

I use Office 2010.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely you have managed to get the "GroupName" property set to the wrong value on one or more of your radiobuttons.

Check the output from this sub:

```
Sub buttons()
    Dim s As Worksheet, o As Object
    For Each s In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each o In s.OLEObjects
            If TypeName(o.Object) = "OptionButton" Then
                Debug.Print "Sheet: " & s.Name, _
                            "        Button: " & o.Name, _
                            "        Group: " & o.Object.GroupName
            End If
        Next o
        Debug.Print "------------------"
    Next s
End Sub
```

Comment: + 1 BullsEye  on `GroupName`

Comment: That's it! I didn't think that GroupNames are global across all sheets.Thanks

Comment: You know, having looked through all the attributes prior to Googling it was not at all clear to me that `GroupName` was the field (especially since it's set to "Sheet1" by default).